# Limits and trigonometry. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I've just started learning limits and got to the first wonderful limit. I saw the problem and tried to solve it before reading the solution. Here's my way of thinking ([my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1PsB.jpg)). But my answer is incorrect. I think I cannot substitute the limit value instead of the x but here's a different example that proves this can be done ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4v9A.png)).Could you please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't delete $\sin(3x)\cos(4x)$ from the numerator, so why do you think you can delete $\sin(4x)\cos(3x)$?

Comment: Because someone in the example feels free to replace the x with its value (not in the whole expression but just where It's needed)

Comment: But can't you see that $\sin(3x)\cos(4x)$ and $\sin(4x)\cos(3x)$ have exactly the same form? How on earth could you believe that you could delete one but not the other? And if so, why the second one, and not the first?

Comment: I'd be glad if you explain why the person in the example can do such a substitution and I can't?

Comment: See my answer. (Also, my Russian is rusty, but doesn't it explain already?)

Comment: The guy says we can replace the square root sum in the brackets with the constant but he says nothing about replacing (-9x + 27)/(5x-15) with a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reason that the $x$'s can be replaced by their limit in your Russian example
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 3}\frac{-9x+27}{(5x-15)(\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{10x-21})}$$

We can immediately replace $\dfrac{-9x+27}{5x-15}$ with the constant $-\frac95$. So we are left with
$$\lim_\limits{x\to 3}-\frac95\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+6}+\sqrt{10x-21}}$$

And now we can clearly replace the $x$'s by $3$, because the numerator and denominator are both non-zero at $x=3$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that that thing was a constant. Now the answers about replacing x in the whole function make sense for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error is that when you replace $x=0$ you do not do it everywhere it is for that reason that $\sin(3x)$ survives and the error occurs, the correct thing is to make a variable change: let $u=7x$, as $x\to 0$ then $u\to $. Thus we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(7x)}{3x}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{3\cdot \frac{u}{7}}=\frac{7}{3}\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=\frac{7}{3}
$$
Or in the simplified way it would be:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(7x)}{3x}=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 7x}{x}=\frac{\color{red}{7}}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 7x}{\color{red}{7}x}=\frac{7}{3}
$$

Comment: But what makes it possible to replace the x with its value in the "example" image (note that in that example x is also replaced not everywhere)?

Comment: @VortxLion When you replace the value $x=0$ it must be in the whole function without leaving any x loose, and with it reach a real value or an indeterminacy that will be solved with the methods that you will see in the topic. Look at the example of José Carlos Santos who directly attacks his mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\lim_{x\to}\frac{\sin(7x)}{3x}=\frac73\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(7x)}{7x}=\frac73.$$The problem with your approach lies in the fact that, when you have reached$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(4x)\cos(3x)}{3x},$$you decided to let $x$ go to $0$ in the numerator, but not in the denominator. You cannot do that. If it worked, then$$1=\lim_{x\to0}1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=0,$$since $\lim_{x\to0}x=0$.